# scrapy shell testing xpath invalid syntax

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to retrive reviews from trip advisor and instead of writing code I diciced to use the shell that scrapy comes with. While I was testing this Xpath

```
response.xpath(//div[@id="REVIEWS"]/a/text())
```

I am getting invalid syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
response.xpath('//div[@id="REVIEWS"]/a/text()')
```

Comment: This works for most parts but the array length is 0, even though looking through google chrome's inspect element it seems like it should not be 0